# PDO prepared SELECT statement isn't working

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

i'm having a hard time trying to retrieve data from a table using PDO prepared statements,

Below is my code which isn't working, $post is always empty.

```
    //connection to db has been made
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$_GET['id']);
    $post = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm quite confident the problem occurs in the third line, so please let me know if there is another way to get the data rather than fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).

Thanks alot.

Comment: your `$post = ...` and `$stmt->execute();` are in the wrong order.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant it @user2585384, but the execute method goes between `bindValue` and `fetchAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually executing the method, but otherwise, your code looks fine!

```
// Assuming $_GET['id'] has a value (thanks Mike!)
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();

$post = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As an aside, I'd also make sure that `$_GET['id']` is valid; `is_int($_GET['id'])` returns a boolean that could help.

---

After fetching your posts, make sure to iterate through them.

```
if($post != null && count($post) > 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($post); $i++) {
        echo $post[$i]['title'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `$_GET['id']` actually holds a value.

Comment: Thanks guys, $_GET['id'] is not empty, i tried your code, and i still can't get anything from table 'posts'.

Comment: Hmm...you can see if there was an error by putting this `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());` after the execute call.

Comment: ChrisForrence, i added the var_dump and i got this message "array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" } ", when i use print_r($post), i can actually see the retrieved data inside the array, but i can't print anything out like print $post['title']; ..

Comment: @user2585384 - Ok, that's easy! Basically, `$post` is an array of arrays. Try `echo $post[0]['title'];` and see if you get the first title.

Comment: @user2585384 - No problem! I did update my answer to have an iterator so that you can go through each post.